# How can I access the Description of a company from crunchbase using python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I did try using beautifulSoup but didn't succeed.

```
import urllib2
import tldextract
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
u2 =  urllib2.urlopen("https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/facebook#/entity")
soup = BeautifulSoup(u2)
access_response_2 = soup.find('dl',class = "definition-list-container")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can connect & parse the cruchabse website with urllib2. Last time I tried they were throwing **416 HTTP error**. Then I tried setting useragent, proper HTTP headers and cookie values with urllib2 request but it also failed.

Use the [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead.
With that you will be able to connect to cruchbase page & parse. After connecting to target page, parse it with parser which comes with selenium or you can use beautifulSoup as well

example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/facebook#/entity')
```

parse with selenium

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('definition-list-container')
```

or parse with BeautifulSoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
soup.find('dl',{ 'class' : "definition-list-container"})
```

Comment: I get this error:

>>> driver= webdriver.Firefox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: you need to setup selenium drive proprely

First download the geckodriver from [this link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) , extract the zip file and mention the downloaded driver path in driver initiation statement. eg: `driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='E:\\apps\\geckodriver.exe')`

Comment: I was able to fix that issue.
However your code above doesn't fetch the description of a company from crunchbase. Could you please help me in fixing it? Thanks!

Comment: I know. I just mentioned approach only. You need to use **selectors** to get the required element. Please read selenium / beautiful soup documentation on parsing HTML.

For fetching company description you can use 
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//dt[text()='Description:']/following-sibling::dd").text`